# Confusing python - Cannot convert string to float

Tags: python, error-handling

I got a value error and even if I try playing around with the code, it doesn't work!

How can I get it right? - I am using Python 3.3.2!

Here is the code: [image: Code]

As you can see, the program asks for how many miles you can walk and gives you a response depending on what you type in.

This is the code in text format:

```
print("Welcome to Healthometer, powered by Python...")
miles = input("How many miles can you walk?: ")
if float(miles) <= 0:
    print("Who do you think you are?!! Go and walk 1000 miles now!")
elif float(miles) >= 10:
    print("You are very healthy! Keep it up!")
elif float(miles) > 0 and miles < 10:
    print("Good. Try doing 10 miles")
else:
    print("Please type in a number!")
    miles = float(input("How many miles can you walk?: "))
    if miles <= 0:
        print("Who do you think you are?!! Go and walk 1000 miles now!")
    elif miles >= 10:
        print("You are very healthy! Keep it up!")
    elif miles > 0 and miles < 10:
        print("Good. Try doing 10 miles")
```

Comment: what is the answer to `float("I have no idea")` ?

Comment: Please show code as text and not as graphics - it allows others to use and run the code

Comment: @JoranBeasley: the "else" bit to the bottom

Comment: Why has it been voted down four times? I corrected everything.

Comment: lol i like the spray paint effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the Traceback log says: `Could not convert string to float`

- If you have a string with only numbers, python's smart enough to do what you're trying and converts the string to a float.
- If you have a string with non-numerical characters, the conversion will fail and give you the error that you were having.

The way most people would approach this problem is with a `try/except` (see [here](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)), or using the `isdigit()` function (see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm)).

**Try/Except**

```
try:
    miles = float(input("How many miles can you walk?: "))
except:
    print("Please type in a number!")
```

**Isdigit()**

```
miles = input("How many miles can you walk?: ")
if not miles.isdigit():
    print("Please type a number!")
```

Note that the latter will still return false if there are decimal points in the string

### EDIT

Okay, I won't be able to get back to you for a while, so I'll post the answer just in case.

```
while True:
    try:
        miles = float(input("How many miles can you walk?: "))
        break
    except:
        print("Please type in a number!")

#All of the ifs and stuff
```

The code's really simple:

- It will keep trying to convert the input to a float, looping back to the beginning if it fails.
- When eventually it succeeds, it'll break from the loop and go to the code you put lower down.

Comment: Amazing answer! Try looking at how to implement all this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736880/implementation-of-try-except-in-python

Comment: @TimTimmy Check this link out, see if that gets you there. If not, leave another comment and I'll edit my answer here instead of branching the question to another post: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm

Comment: @TimTimmy Nevermind, I won't be able to get back to you for a while so I put the code in my answer just in case.

Comment: "If you have a string with only numbers, python's smart enough to do what you're trying and converts the string to a " is so annoying — I'm trying to load housing IDs which are all numbers, and Python tries to apply a ton of magic to turn them into floats, and using str() doesn't help

Answer (score 10):

You need to take into account that the user might not fill in a proper value:

```
try:
    miles = float(input("How many miles can you walk? "))
except ValueError:
    print("That is not a valid number of miles")
```

A [`try/except`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) handles the `ValueError` that might occur when `float` tries to convert the input to a float.

Answer (score 2):

The traceback means what it says on the tin.

```
>>> float('22')
22.0
>>> float('a lot')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a lot'
```

`float` can convert strings that look like valid decimals into `float`s.  It can't convert arbitrary alphanumeric strings, notably including `'How am I supposed to know?'`.

If you want to handle arbitrary user input, you have to catch this exception, with a `try/except` block.

Answer (score 1):

The point here it can not convert alphanumeric strings, in some cases if you are scraping data or something like $400, $ symbol is alphanumeric then it consider an string, if you try convert  to float it display an error, i give you this example to show it only convert numbers to float, in this case i solved the problem like this data ='$400', price = data[1:], then if , if (float(price) < 300): and it works.