# Error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code works perfectly to find the average of the numbers in the file it references however I cannot seem to get it to find the standard deviation.
The equation for standard deviation is: Square root/(n1-a)^2+(n2-a)^2/m

-everything is under the square root i could not find the character for it

-N1,N2.....Nm=the numbers that are in the list being referenced

-a=average

-m=total number of numbers in the list

here's what I have,

```
def main():
    numbersFile=open("RandomNumber.txt" , 'r')

    line=numbersFile.readline()
    total=0
    numberoflines=0

    while line != "":
        numberoflines+=1
        total+=int(line)
        line=numbersFile.readline().strip()
    average=total/numberoflines
    std=line-average
    deviation=(std**2)/numberoflines


    print("The average is: " , average)
    print("The standard deviation of the numbers is: " , deviation)


main()
```

Comment: presumably this line `std=line-average` `line` is a `str` so the error is pretty clear

Comment: how would you suggest I convert it?

Comment: be aware that **numberoflines** might contain characters that are not digits

Comment: @JaredVenson have you tried using the `float()` function on your lines?

Comment: @joel yes, still doesnt seem to work

Comment: @JaredVenson why doesn't it work? Are you getting a traceback?

Answer (score 2):

Your `line` variable is a string returned by `file.readline()`. You need to convert it to a `float` first before you can perform subtraction with another float.

Change:

```
std=line-average
```

to:

```
std=float(line)-average
```

Comment: std=float(line)-average
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Make sure all the lines in the file are indeed valid numbers.

Comment: they are, the averages are being printed out fine

Comment: Now that I reread your code, I see that `lin` has to be an empty string in order to break the `while` loop, so the `line` in your `std=line-average` is always an empty string, and would therefore result in `ValueError` when you try to convert it to `float`. You need to rewrite your loop so that `std` is calculated inside the loop for each value of the input lines.

Comment: thats difficult because average needs to be defined before I can call it in the std equation

Comment: You can store the values from your input lines into a list first and then calculate `std` in another loop based on the list after you obtain the average.

Comment: I am familiar with the list, but not that advanced in it..would it look something like a[ ]=int(line) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736589/confusing-python-cannot-convert-string-to-float) regarding **try/except** and **isdigit()**, after that
do some casts to float before computing the **deviation**, something like this:

```
std=float(line)-float(average)
deviation=float((std**2))/float(numberoflines)
```

Also keep in mind that your **line** from `line=numbersFile.readline()` might contain characters that are not digits, double check your input. Because you use **line** in `std=line-average` and you know for sure that **average** is correct, the problem is with **line** and **std** gets the wrong value.

Comment: with testing this my error is not being able to convert string to float. line: std=float(line)-float(average)

Answer (score 0):

correct source code to calculate:

```
import math
def main():
numbersFile=open("RandomNumber.txt" , 'r')

line=numbersFile.readline()
total=0
numberoflines=0

while line != "":

    numberoflines+=1
    total+=float(line)


    line=numbersFile.readline().rstrip('\n')
numbersFile.seek(0)
average=total/numberoflines
line=numbersFile.readline()
total=0
while line !="":
    line=float(line)-average
    a=line**2
    total+=a
    line=numbersFile.readline()
std=math.sqrt(total/numberoflines)







print("The average is: " , average)

print("The standard deviation of the numbers is: " , std)


main()
```