# How to solve "ValueError: could not convert string to float" in Python?

Tags: pyqt5

I'm new to Python GUI programming and have got stuck on a small problem. Here is my code:

```
    for product in products:
        self.productCombo.addItem(product[1],product[0])
        self.taxEntry.setText(product[2])

    self.igst = product[3]
    self.netrate = self.netRateEntry.text()
    self.rate =(float(self.netrate)/100)+(float(self.igst))*100
    print(self.rate)
    self.rateEntry.setText(self.rate)
```

Getting this error:

```
File "D:\PyQt\Sellproduct.py", line 180, in Widgets  
self.rate =(float(self.netrate)/100)+(float(self.igst))*100 
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusing python - Cannot convert string to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736589/confusing-python-cannot-convert-string-to-float)

Comment: Put before this line: `print(self.netrate); print(self.igst)` and you will see everything.

Comment: Thank you so much sir it helped me but when I tried print(float(self.netrate)) it is still giving the error that could not convert string to float